# Angular, woocommerce, wordpress JWT AUTH login error, incorrect 200 OK Response from server possibly sabotaging the login attempt

Tags: angular, wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, jwt

I am having some issues with JWT-AUTH on wordpress with my ionic app. I have watched a tutorial series on youtube, for creating an ionic app with wordpress and woocommerce. I downloaded the code and integrated most of it within my own app, however, the login is giving me some grief.

I have tested JWT auth requests, and I do receive a valid token, so I do not believe the issue is with the plugin. It also stores in the cache which is intended. Regardless, there still seems to be an issue.

Firstly, when I login, my authState variable is set to true, even with completely random credentials. Testing with insomnia, and the exact same data gives an expected 403 error.

I think the invalid authState being set to true incorrectly is the root of the problem. I am still a beginner-moderate coder, so I understand the code, and I think it should be working but obviously it isn't. I think I understand the error, but don't  know whats causing it. I hope I've provided the correct code and all the info.

**login.page.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl || null;
    this.authService.authState$.subscribe((state) => {
      this.authState = state;
      console.log(this.authState);
      if (this.authState) {
        if (this.returnUrl !== null) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl).then();
        } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/").then();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  login(loginForm: NgForm) {
    if (loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      const { email, password } = loginForm.value;
      this.authService.login(email, password).then();
    }
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  async login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(SkipInterceptor, "");
    const loader = await this.loadingController.create({
      animated: true,
      backdropDismiss: true,
      message: "Authenticating Account",
      spinner: "crescent",
      id: "auth",
    });

    await loader.present().then();

    if (!this.currentAuthState) {
      this.httpClient
        .post(`${this.WP_AUTH_URL}`, { username, password }, { headers })
        .subscribe(
          async (data: AuthResponse) => {
            await loader.dismiss().then();
            if (data.token !== null) {
              this.storage.set("data", { ...data }).then((resp) => {
                this.currentAuthState = true;
                this.authState$.next(this.currentAuthState);
                this.fetchUserDetails(data.user_email)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then((user: CustomerModel) => {
                    this.storage.set("user", user);
                    console.log(user);
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]).then();
                  });
              });
            } else {
              this.currentAuthState = false;
              this.authState$.next(this.currentAuthState);
            }
          },
          async (err: ErrorResponse) => {
            await loader.dismiss().then();
            this.currentAuthState = false;
            this.authState$.next(this.currentAuthState);
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (err.status === 403) {
                const alert = await this.alertController.create({
                  message: "Bad Username Or Password",
                  buttons: [
                    {
                      role: "cancel",
                      text: "Ok",
                    },
                  ],
                  header: "Authentication Failed",
                });

                await alert.present().then();
              } else {
                const alert = await this.alertController.create({
                  message: err.statusText,
                  buttons: [
                    {
                      role: "cancel",
                      text: "Ok",
                    },
                  ],
                  header: "Authentication Failed",
                });

                await alert.present().then();
              }
            }
          }
        );
    } else {
      await loader.dismiss().then();
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/").then();
      return;
    }
  }
```

Now this part of the code is returning an undefined email, which I believe is being caused by the error response from the login, which is leading to the failed login attempt (although the login credntials are stored)
Also, if I do the exact same (well what I believe to be the exact same) request in insomnia, and manually provide the email, i receive an empty array.

**auth.service.ts**

```
  private fetchUserDetails(email: string) {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${this.serverUrl}/customers?email=${email}`)
      .pipe(take(1));
  }
```

console error for the above. I think this is being caused by an incorrect response from the server?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!
Turns out my code was indeed correct after all. After rapidly running out of ideas I started to look at the plugins. The JWT auth plugin I used was successfully sending a token, however, for some reason, it was not working. Swapped out the JWT auth plugin on WordPress, and it instantly worked.